# Word splitting in positional parameters

Tags: variable, arguments, variable-substitution, parameter, bash-expansion

Consider the following example:

```
IFS=:
x="a   :b"   # three spaces
echo ["$x"]  # no word splitting
# [a   :b]   # as is
echo [$x]    # word splitting 
# [a    b]   # four spaces
```

Word splitting identifies the the words `"a   "` (three spaces) and `"b"`, separated by the colon, then `echo` joins the words with a space in the middle.
However, when using the value of `$x` as a function argument, I find it difficult to interpret the results.

```
args(){ echo ["$*"];}
args a   :b  # three spaces
# [a::b]
```

and:

```
args(){ echo [$*];}
args a   :b  # three spaces
# [a  b]     # two spaces
```

`$*` expands to the value of all the positional parameters combined. Also, `"$*"` is equivalent to `"$1c$2"`, where `c` is the first character of the value of the IFS variable.

```
args(){ echo ["$1"]["$2"]; }
args a   :b  # three spaces
# [a][:b]
```

and:

```
args(){ echo [$1][$2]; }
args a   :b  # three spaces
# [a][ b]
```

Word splitting should always occur when there are unquoted expansions. Here `"$1"` and `$1` are the same and in both cases they do not use the `:` delimiter. `[$2]` -> `[ b]` is also unclear.

Probably, before applying IFS-splitting, other tokenization rules are used, but I was unable to find them.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Word splitting only applies to unquoted expansions (parameter expansion, arithmetic expansion and command substitution) in modern Bourne-like shells (in `zsh`, only command substitution unless you use an emulation mode).

When you do:

```
args a    :b
```

Word splitting is not involved at all.

It's the shell parsing that tokenises those, finds the first one is not one of its keywords and so it's a simple command with 3 arguments: `args`, `a` and `:b`. The amount of space won't make any difference there. Note that it's not only spaces, also tabs, and in some shells (like `yash` or `bash`) any character considered as *blank* in you locale (though in the case of `bash`, not the multibyte ones)¹.

Even in the Bourne shell where word splitting also applied to unquoted arguments of commands regardless of whether  they were the result of expansions or not, that would be done **on top** (long after) the tokenising and syntax parsing.

In the Bourne shell, in

```
IFS=i
while bib=did edit foo
```

That would not *parse* that as:

```
"wh" "le b" "b=d" "d ed" "t foo"
```

But first as a `while` with a simple command and the `edit` word (as it's an argument but not the `bid=did` word which is an assignment) of that simple command would be *further* split into `ed` and `t` so that the `ed` command with the 3 arguments `ed`, `t` and `foo` would be run as the condition of that `while` loop.

Word splitting is *not* part of the syntax parsing. It's like an operator that is applied implicitly to arguments (also in `for` loop words, arrays and with some shell the target of redirections and [a few other contexts](/a/382914)) for the parts of them that are not quoted. What's confusing is that it's done *implicitly*. You don't do `cmd split($x)`, you do `cmd $x` and the `split()` ([actually `glob(split())`](/q/171346)) is implied. In `zsh`, you have to request it explicitly for parameter expansions (`split($x)` is `$=x` there  (`$=` looking like a pair of scissors)).

So, now, for your examples:

> ```
> args(){ echo ["$*"];}
> args a   :b  # three spaces
> # [a::b]
> ```

`a` and `:b` arguments of `args` joined with the first character of `$IFS` which gives `a::b` (note that it's a bad idea of using `[...]` here as it's a globbing operator).

> ```
> args(){ echo [$*];}
> args a   :b  # three spaces
> # [a  b]     # two spaces
> ```

`$*` (which contains `a::b`) is split into `a`, the empty string and `b`. So it's:

```
echo '[a' '' 'b]'
```

> ```
> args(){ echo ["$1"]["$2"]; }
> args a   :b  # three spaces
> # [a][:b]
> ```

no surprise as not word splitting.

> ```
> args(){ echo [$1][$2]; }
> args a   :b  # three spaces
> # [a][ b]
> ```

That's like:

```
 echo '[a]' '[' 'b]'
```

as  `$2` (`:b`) would be split into the empty string and `b`.

One case where you will see variations between implementations is when `$IFS` is empty.

In:

```
set a b
IFS=
printf '<%s>\n' $*
```

In some shells (most nowadays), you see

```
<a>
<b>
```

And not `<ab>` even though `"$*"` would expand to `ab`. Those shells still separate those `a` and `b` position parameters and that has now been made a POSIX requirement in the latest version of the standard.

If you did:

```
set a b
IFS=
var="$*" # note that the behaviour for var=$* is unspecified
printf '<%s>\n' $var
```

you'd see `<ab>` as the information that `a` and `b` were 2 separate arguments was lost when assigned to `$var`.

---

¹, of course, it's not only blanks that delimit words. Special tokens in the shell syntax do as well, the list of which depends on the context. In most contexts, `|`, `||`, `&`, `;`, newline, `<`, `>`, `>>`... delimit words. In `ksh93` for instance, you can write a blank-less command like:

```
while({([[(:)]])})&&((1||1))do(:);uname<&2|tee>(rev)file;done
```

Comment: Thank you. So I should have word splitting, given `IFS=:` and `x="foo :bar"`, in `args $x`. What would be the sequence here? For example, after the token `args` and `$x` are identified, the latter is expanded and retokenised.

Comment: @antonio, there's no _retokensing_, there's the tokenising that is done when the shell parses its syntax, and there's word splitting, a special operator applied to unquoted expansions. With `args $x`, it's as if you had written `run_simple_command("args", split($x))` in another language (well `run_simple_command(glob("args"), glob(split($x)))` as globbing applies as well). While for the Bourne shell, it would have been like `run_simple_command(glob(split("args")), glob(split($x)))`. See also: [Security implications of forgetting to quote a variable in bash/POSIX shells](/q/171346)

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I think there is inaccuracy here (second example): `$* (which contains a::b) is split into a, the empty string and b.` Why `$*` is `a::b`? I think next: the `$1` = `a`, `$2` = `:b` and `$*` processes the `a` without changes, then splits the `:b` to two parts - the left is empty string and the right is `b`. So, we get `{a}{}{b}`. Try `args :b`. You also get empty string - `{}{b}`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas I was used this code for testing: `args(){
    echo '$1 = '"$1";
    echo '$2 = '"$2";
    printf '{%s}' $*;
    echo "";
}

args :b;
args a   :b;  
`

Comment: @MiniMax, that boils down to my empty IFS case. Wether `$*` becomes split into "a", "" and "b" because it's separate "a" and ":b" split into "" and "b" (like in some shells), or because if's $* first joined into "a::b" and then split into "a", "" and "b" (like in some other shells) produces the same result in all cases anyway _except the empty IFS_ case.