# Is there a way to make word splitting work with a non-space delimiter when not using a variable?

Tags: bash, shell

If I do something like this:

```
IFS=,
x=hello,hi,world
echo $x
```

Then three arguments will be extracted (which are `hello` and `hi` and `world`), and these three arguments will be passed to `echo`.

But when I do not use a variable:

```
IFS=,
echo hello,hi,world bye
```

Then word splitting will happen using the space delimiter and not the comma delimiter, and so the two arguments generated and passed to `echo` will be`hello,hi,world` and `bye`.

Is there a way to make word splitting work with a non-space delimiter when not using a variable?

Comment: Could you give a practical example of where you plan to use this? I assume you don't just want to `echo` something, and suspect this might be an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). If you give an example of the specific use case you have in mind, we might be able to give you a better solution.

Comment: @terdon I don't plan to use this anywhere, I am just trying to understand how word splitting works.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. In that case, the answer below should be what you need.

Comment: @user267935, you may also be interested in [this answer by Stéphane Chazelas from a while back](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408622/170373).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, word splitting happens only after expansions, not on stuff given directly on the command line (on modern shells, that is). The [text in POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05) says:

> **2.6.5 Field Splitting**
>   After parameter expansion (Parameter Expansion), command substitution (Command Substitution), and arithmetic expansion (Arithmetic Expansion), *the shell shall scan the results of expansions and substitutions* that did not occur in double-quotes for field splitting and multiple fields can result.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

And [Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Word-Splitting.html#Word-Splitting):

> The shell scans the results of parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion that did not occur within double quotes for word splitting.

I'm not sure that's much of a problem, since you could just replace the commas with spaces if the string is directly in the script. And if it comes from the outside, then splitting usually happens naturally, in a command substitution or when using `read`, etc.

---

In the original Bourne shell, the behaviour was a bit different, [@Stéphane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/st%C3%A9phane-chazelas) 
discussed this in [an answer to another question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/408622/170373) a while back

Comment: Strictly speaking, op didn’t ask about expansions. They asked about a variable. So `IFS=,; echo $(echo hello,hi,world bye)` should do the trick by invoking an expansion without using a variable per se.

Comment: @kojiro, invoking a subshell to avoid the use of a variable is even worse...

Comment: I wasn’t making a qualitative point about worse or better. I’m just drawing the distinction between an expansion and a name.

Answer (score 0):

The first splitting of the command line is done on metacharacters:

> metacharacter
>                 A character that, when unquoted, separates words.  One of the following:
>                 |  & ; ( ) < > space tab newline

That's before any expansion, before any word splitting (after expansions).
That happens regardless of the value of IFS.

A coma is not a metacharacter, thus a line (initially) will not be split on it.